# Angular 6+, Ability to securely create users from application

Tags: node.js, angular, security, server

just a quick question because I am at a loss right now about the security logics behind creating users as an Admin in the application.

I mean, I have a form and I can add an username and a password for someone to connect as an user in the application, but how do I securely send the request to my server with the informations to add the users to the database

My backend and frontend servers are behind HTTPs. Are http POST requests inside the app secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the POST method is a safe request as long as you are using HTTPS protocol. HTTPS prevents Man in the Middle Attack and hence nobody would be able to tamper your information in transit to your web server.

As a side note, you should have a valid token like JWT, which would be authorize the sender of the information to create users for your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am currently using JWT. About Man in the Middle Attacks, they might not be able to tamper the information but what about reading the information and knowing the username and password for a user I want to create ?

Comment: HTTPS employs asymmetric algorithm and hence the information in transit is encrypted which can only be decrypted by the entity possessing the private key. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks I will code my mind now. I will also read more on that!

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeDufour Great :)